# TYPO3 Scheduler does nothing

Tags: php, cron, scheduler, typo3-7.6.x

I've written a scheduler task. Its working fine on my maching. Unfortunately its not working on my remote machine.

The machine is a freeBSD with php7.0 php-fpm running. 
The cron looks like:

```
**MAILTO=mail@falk-roeder.de
@weekly /usr/local/bin/letsencrypt.sh -c
* * * * * php /var/www/alpha/beta/gamma/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler
#* * * * * php -r 'echo function_exists("foo") ? "yes" : "no";'
```

the last crontab is executed (if I comment it in) and mail output sent to me.

If I replace "scheduler" with something weird, I also get a mail with the output which contains the valid options I should choose. 
So that means for me, that cron is running and the cli_dispatch.phpsh is called correctly.

In TYPO3 Backend the scheduler says the configuration is fine. I can manually start the cron and its doing the job.

So, what else could the reason be...?

**EDIT**

I figured out that the reason is, that the TYPO3 Scheduler didn't request the correct database. I've an AdditionalConfiguration file where the database name  in $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['database'] is changed based on the variable $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. But in Scheduler this variable is empty. So I had to delete the AdditionalConfiguration file and everything is working as espected.

The question now is, how can I achieve Scheduler getting the right Database based on Servername?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others more complete answer:

In .htaccess you set the Application Context of your site based on youtr hostname.

Example:

```
# Rules to set ApplicationContext based on hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.de$
RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alpha\.example\.de$
RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production/Staging]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.de$
RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production]
```

In your AdditionalConfiguration.php you set the DB based on this Context.
Example:

```
if (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getApplicationContext()->isDevelopment()) {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['database'] = 'typo376_dev';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['username'] = 'typo376_dev_usr';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['password'] = 'somepw';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['clearCacheSystem'] = '1';
} elseif (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getApplicationContext() == 'Production/Staging') {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['database'] = 'typo376_alpha';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['username'] = 'typo376_alpha_usr';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['password'] = 'someotherpw';
} else if(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getApplicationContext() == 'Production') {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['database'] = 'typo376';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['username'] = 'typo376_usr';
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['password'] = 'someotherpw';
```

}

In your cron tab (edit it with crontab -e on your command line) you set the Envroiment Variable before you call the cliscript.

Example:

```
* * * * * TYPO3_CONTEXT=Production/Staging php /var/www/alpha/beta/gamma/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler
```

Comment: Just important side note: The Context Testing must only be used for testing, means unit tests, functional tests. use a subcontext of development or production like Production/Testing for an environment like QS!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the server variable better use the application context which can also be set while calling the scheduler

Comment: Danke. Das ist perfekt.